# Setting up a Database Diagram in VS2012 & SSDT?

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I'm working myself through this book called Head First C#.NET as I want to get into programming.

Basically the book was written for VS2010, but since my employer has bought me a MSDN License, I decided to go for VS2012 instead.

One of the assignments in the book is to create a local database, and make a database diagram for it. Unfortunately, this functionality has been removed from VS itself from VS2012 and upwards.

I've already googled it, and read that this was replaced by SSDT. Hence, I installed SSDT but I'm still not able to view and/or create a Database Diagram.

Is the "Diagram" functionality completely deprecated from 2012 and should I be looking at something complete different to get what I want / need?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174885.aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that article is about multidimensional models. The instructions don't seem to provide a way to represent tables in a diagram.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/24c9878f-e553-489d-8353-c97976eeb04e), there is no diagram support in SSDT.